# Remote calls in Custom Function Batching

Tags: office365, office-js

Custom function batching - I have taken batching example from MSDN using the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-batching.

But could not find how to pass a sample API request in the _fetchFromRemoteService function. It would be great if you can point out the syntax on how to actually use the get or post API request.

For instance,

const url = "https://api.github.com/repos/" + userName + "/" + repoName;

Thanks
Cris

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-batching

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the tutorial on how to make the web request. You can use both fetch and xmlhttprequests to make the web service calls.

The documentation used a generic sample as each service endpoint may expect the data to be different.